# Writing problem after placing a group of variables in a specific section with IAR arm linker

Tags: c, hyperlink, arm, freertos, iar

*Hello everybody ,
I would like to ask you because I need something.
I used the cisdous lines to place a group of variables in a specific area

```
/* Place following data in section MY_DATA */
#pragma default_variable_attributes = @ "MY_DATA"

int data1;

/* Stop placing data in section MY_DATA */
#pragma default_variable_attributes =
int data2;
```

I checked everything is going well. The variables are well placed in the specific area. However, when I modify the variables (data1=80), nothing happens.
The variable always remains at 0

Could anyone help me?
THANK YOU D4AVANCE

Comment: Everythinhg is in the IAR documewntation